# Validation of BST using Inorder Traversal recursively

Tags: c, function, recursion, binary-search-tree

consider a binary tree in c with structure given below

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};
```

And this is the code for to check if a given tree is Binary Search Tree or not

```
int isBST(struct  node* root){
static struct node *prev = NULL;
if(root!=NULL){
    if(!isBST(root->left)){
        return 0;
    }
    if(prev!=NULL && root->data <= prev->data){
        return 0;
    }
    prev = root;
    return isBST(root->right);
}
else{
    return 1;
}
}
```

I want to know why we made the **node prev static** and when does this part of the code section violate the criteria for BST

```
if(!isBST(root->left)){
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your function will fail when, for example, it checks a tree with only one (root) node twice.

Comment: *"I want to know why we made the node prev static"*: that would be the question I would like to ask *you*? Why did you? It is not the way to go...

Comment: There is no check that `root->data` is larger than the `root->left->data` (if it exists). Also, do not use a static variable, just compare `root->data` with the child before recursing into the child.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rnMPs8d4o <- using the `static` variable to produce a wrong answer. You definitely shouldn't use static in this. Even if the rest was correct, the function would then be single-use only.

Comment: @teapot418 then do i declare it as global variable or is there some other way of doing it

Comment: You don't need to use `prev` at all.

Comment: A tree is a BST iff: the root is null; the left subtree is a BST; the right subtree is a BST; if the left node is not null and its data is smaller than the current node; if the right node is not null and its data is larger than the current node.  You can make those tests in almost any order that suits you, but the root node is null test must be first.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.